# Linkedin scraper can't read Open Graph information

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

The Linkedin scraper can't read our Wordpress website (https://www.aeternuscompany.nl/) Open Graph data. If people share an update in Linkedin with a link of our website, the Link-preview leaves empty. In Facebook this works fine.

We tried different things:

- Another theme
- Different Share plugins
- Different open Graph plugins
- We ask the hosting-company if there see some problems (everything
  seems correct)
- We also check socialdebug.com for debugs in Open Graph data

[See image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LElK9.png)

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Open graph tags are added properly in you website.

As per LinkedIn docs (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin),

> The first time that LinkedIn's crawlers visit a webpage when asked to
>   share content via a URL, the data it finds (Open Graph values or our
>   own analysis) will be cached for a period of approximately 7 days.

Try after couple of days to check if your changes are reflected.

Comment: Thank you Rifaj for your answer. Good to now that the Open Graph tags are added properly. 

I know that the Linkedin crawler caches the website for 7 days. Unfortunately the problem isn't solved at the moment. The linkedin-link preview is still empty. Maybe you know another solution?

Comment: Try removing the og:image width and height tags. Also remove the og:image:secure_url

Comment: Thank you again Rifaj, I deleted the og:image widt and height tags and the inage:secure_url. The problem still exsists. 

I was wondering: maybe the .htaccess file block the Linkedin bot? Is this possible and what doI have to check?

Comment: Maybe. Update your robots.txt to explicitly allow LinkedinBots. 
User-agent: LinkedInBot
Disallow: /admin

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled about the same problem for our Wordpress site. The problem is created by conflicting OGP and oembed headers in standard wordpress + yoast seo plugin.

You need to disabled the oembed headers with this plugin (this has no side effects): https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-embeds/

After that you can force a fresh link preview by appending a `?1` to your homepage while sharing

`https://www.aeternuscompany.nl/?1`

I wrote a detailed explanation for the problem here: https://pmig.at/2017/10/26/linkedin-link-preview-for-wordpress/